# Geometry Modifier shows only after save/reload of blender file

Tags: python, mesh, add-on, geometry-nodes

In a python add-on (operator) I create a number of mesh objects and attach to each a Geometry Modifier (to show wireframe). The challenge here is that the modifiers do not show in the viewport, only the base mesh. To get them to show i have to either:

1. save and reload the blender file or
2. toggle the "Display Modifier in Viewport" icon "off" and "on" in all modifiers.

When I run only the part of the script which adds the modifiers in the Text Editor, the modifier shows correctly. The add-on script is quite large, and I have tried `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`.

Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of your interface ? Have you tried `obj.data.update()` too ?

Comment: Problem solved. Since i also add hide/unhide animation to the objects i noticed that when i disable adding this animation, the GN modifier shows correctly on all objects. I then added 'obj.hide_viewport=False' and 'obj.data.update()' right AFTER adding the hide/unhide animation and now everything shows correctly. The 'obj.data.update()' right after creating the mesh and object but before adding the animation did not solve the problem. Many thanks for the suggestion Gorgious.